# Por que me sale java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1 "

Tags: java

Buenas noches, estoy leyendo un txt y le quiero insertar los datos que tiene a una tabla de mysql pero me salta esta excepcion:

> NumberFormatException: For input string: "1 ".

```
 File archivo = new File ("D:\\"+nombretxt+".txt");
Scanner s = new Scanner (archivo);
PreparedStatement pst=conexion.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO 'countries'  (id, country_code, country_name) VALUES (?,?,?)");
while (s.hasNextLine()){
String linea =s.nextLine();
Scanner s2 = new Scanner (linea);
s2.useDelimiter("[;\n]");



   pst.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(s2.next())); //Aca me larga el error
   pst.setString(2,s2.next());
   pst.setString(3, s2.next());
pst.executeUpdate();




}
s.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es mejor controlar tú el código, y no que el código te controle a ti, obligándote luego a hacer conversiones de tipos.

Si en cada línea hay un valor entero, lo puedes buscar en el Scanner:

```
while (s.hasNextLine())
{
    String linea =s.nextLine();
    Scanner s2 = new Scanner (linea);
    s2.useDelimiter("[;\n]");

    if (s2.hasNextInt()) 
    {
        int intValor=s2.nextInt();
    }

    //Para mi gusto almacenaría todo en variables
    pst.setInt(1,intValor); //Aca me larga el error
    pst.setString(2,s2.next());
    pst.setString(3, s2.next());
    pst.executeUpdate();

}
s.close();
```

Comment: Estaba bien como lo habia hecho, solamente tenia el error cuando lo queria guardar en la tabla de la bd. Lo guardaba con espacios,así que al momento de leerlo, lo imprimí en pantalla y me di cuenta que me lo imprimía con esos espacios.. por eso me saltaba esa excepción. Lo que hice fue borrarle esos espacios que le había puesto al momento de escribir el txt. Muchas gracias a ambos por responder!

Answer (score 0):

Quitale el enter:

```
Scanner s2 = new Scanner (linea.trim());
```

**Actualizada:**

Si estas tratando de ingresar un entero entonces usa:

```
int linea =s.nextInt();
```

Comment: Lo quite y nada :/

Comment: es que seria id entero , country_code String y country_name String

Comment: Has 3 lecturas distintas, una para entero y dos para string

Comment: El error sigue estando, me tira siempre lo mismo!

Comment: Efectivamente era lo de los espacios.. pero era al momento de escribir en el txt donde yo los coloque sin darme cuenta